# How to print 'AND' between array elements?

Tags: arrays, perl

If I have an array with name like below.

How do I print "Hi joe and jack and john"?

The algorithm should also work, when there is only one name in the array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @a = qw /joe jack john/;

my $mesg = "Hi ";

foreach my $name (@a) {

    if ($#a == 0) {
    $mesg .= $name;
    } else {
    $mesg .= " and " . $name;
    }
}

print $mesg;
```

Comment: http://www.ideone.com/iN2dt ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually we use an array join method to accomplish this. Here pseudo code:

```
@array = qw[name1 name2 name2];
print "Hey ", join(" and ", @array), ".";
```

Comment: Thanks Henning to convert this into Perl. The concept stays the same, however.

Answer (score 2):

Untested:

```
{ local $, = " and "; print "Hi "; print  @a; }
```

Comment: How can you untest a one-liner? Do `perl -e`! (I'm joking:p)

Comment: $, means: The string to print between array elements.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the special variable `$"`.

```
$"="and"; #" (this last double quote is to help the syntax coloring)
$mesg="Hi @a";
```

Answer (score 2):

To collect the [`perldoc perlvar`](http://p3rl.org/var) answers, you may do one of (at least) two things.

1) Set `$"` (list separator):

> When an array or an array slice is interpolated into a double-quoted
>   string or a similar context such as /.../ , its elements are separated
>   by this value. Default is a space. For example, this:

```
print "The array is: @array\n";
```

> is equivalent to this:

```
print "The array is: " . join($", @array) . "\n";
```

=> `$"` affects the behavior of the interpolation of the array into a string

2) Set `$,` (output field separator):

> The output field separator for the print operator. If defined, this
>   value is printed between each of print's arguments. Default is undef.
>   Mnemonic: what is printed when there is a "," in your print statement.

=> `$,` affects the behavior of the `print` statement.

Either will work, and either may be used with `local` to set the value of the special variable only within an enclosing scope. I guess the difference is that with `$"` you are not limited to the print command:

```
my @z = qw/ a b c /;
local $" = " and ";
my $line = "@z";
print $line;
```

here the "magic" happens on the 3rd line not at the print command.

In truth though, using `join` is the most readable, and unless you use a small enclosing block, a future reader might not notice the setting of a magic variable (say nearer the top) and never see that the behavior is not what is expected vs normal performance. I would save these tricks for small one-offs and one-liners and use the readable `join` for production code.